# Port forwarding Visual studio from remote machine?

Tags: visual-studio, networking, remote-desktop

I'm remoting into a development machine and working with visual studio 2017. I'm wondering if it's at all possible to do some port forwarding so when I'm debugging my application through visual studio in the remote machine that I can access the site through my local machine?

Comment: Sure, but this might possibly be a question more for networking.SE. You would want to set up the port forwarding/NAT on the router. But that depends on how the network is set up where the remote machine is hosted.

Comment: Clearly Visual Studio has remote debugger. I am not sure why you cannot set up remote debugging and then access the site through your local machine. Describe the exact issue you met, not just a rough statement.